# php output of print 0500

Tags: php

I have following php code.

```
    <?php
           print 0505;
           echo "\n";
           print 0500;
     ?>

output =>   325
            320
```

can anyone tell me how come did this output?

Comment: Here in the string there is 0 in the starting of number. so it is treated as a octal value. that's why it is giving such value.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php - Integers can be specified in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), **octal (base 8)** [...] To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0x*** - hex number (16)
0b*** - bin number (2, PHP5.4)
0*** - oct number (8) 
*** - dec number (10, normal)

Answer (score 4):

This is octal

[Here](http://www.statman.info/conversions/octal.html) is a octal/decimal converter.

500 oct = 320 dec

505 oct = 325 dec

Answer (score 0):

You can get output using this format

print "0505";

echo "\n";

print "0500";

Because this is octal/decimal convertor

please check this link: http://www.statman.info/conversions/octal.html